# The command "esriRegasm.exe ..." exited with code -1. I can't build a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, arcmap, arcobjects

I want to build the project to create a tool with ArcObjects in Visual Studio. I get this error:

```
The command "esriRegasm.exe "...Project1.dll" /p:Desktop /s" exited with code -1.
```

I use C#, Visual Studio 2015, ArcObjects 10.5, ArcMap 10.5.

I looked at past questions with the same error ([External tool (esriRegasm.exe) fails during build. Where in my VS project is it executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856328/external-tool-esriregasm-exe-fails-during-build-where-in-my-vs-project-is-it/23700135#23700135)).

I tried to solve the problem like this:

- tried to open the solution as an "adminimtrator" not just a user;
- run the `esriRegAsm.exe` command from the command line. I tried in two ways. The first, as in the error in Visual Studio ([picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkWeF.png)) and the second, as per the instructions on the help.arcgis website. ([picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRlV8.png));
- tried to open the .csproj file, go to the end of the file, find the line `esriRegAsm.exe`, delete it and rebuild the project.

None of this worked. How to build a project?

Comment: I quite often stumble over that error and never really nailed it down. Usually I just delete the `BeforeClean`- and `AfterBuild`-targets within the csproj-file, where the call usually is defined. However I suggest to go to `gis.stackexchange` with questions related to ArcGIS.

Comment: Anway what happens when you righclick your assembly and select register?

Comment: The error reporting is too lame to tell you what went wrong.  You need to know the InnerException but it won't tell you.  Debug it with Project > Properties > Debug tab, select "Start external program" and type the command.  Next use Debug > Windows > Exception Settings and tick CLR Exceptions.  Press F5 and the debugger should stop at the statement in your code that caused the exception.  Typically it is the initialization of a static variable that keels over.

Comment: @HansPassant In the "Start external program" field, I have the path to ArcMap.exe. Do I need to change it? I selected all "CLR Exceptions".

Comment: @HimBromBeere I didn't understand where I need to press the right button and find "registration". I am a beginner, thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Did you review [this](https://community.esri.com/thread/108044)?

Comment: you can rightclick your compiled assembly - assuming you have the ArcObjects SDK installed - and select register/unreigster from there, which eventually does also call esriregasm.

Comment: Furthermore you can disable the `/s`-flag from your call within the build-task. Maybe you get more meaningful error then - probably not.

Answer (score 2):

The esriregasm-tool is used to register your own commands, tools or extension for using in ArcGIS. It is usually defined as msbuild-task at the end of your csproj-file as follows:

```
<Target Name="BeforeClean" Condition=" '$(NO_ESRI_REGASM)' == '' ">
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(CommonProgramFiles)\ArcGIS\bin" Command="esriRegasm.exe &quot;$(TargetPath)&quot; /p:Desktop /u /s" Condition="Exists('$(TargetPath)')" />
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(NO_ESRI_REGASM)' == '' ">
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(CommonProgramFiles)\ArcGIS\bin" Command="esriRegasm.exe &quot;$(TargetPath)&quot; /p:Desktop /s" />
</Target>
```

As I get this eror on nearly **every** rebuild of my solution, I developed a couple of strategies to handle it.

First you can just build the project again. As this won´t invoke the forementioned targets - only on "Clean" or "Rebuild", but not on "Build" - the registration is not executed. However your assembly is created. You can still register it after being compiled, either by rightclicking on the dll-file and selecting Register, or by calling the following within the commandline:

```
%CommonProgramFiles%\ArcGIS\bin\esriregasm /p:Desktop /u
%CommonProgramFiles%\ArcGIS\bin\esriregasm /p:Desktop
```

Be aware that I omitted the `/s`-flag in order to get more meaningul errors. You can also append the `/e`-switch for more verbose errors - which is not really much from my experience.

Now look into folder where the ECFG-files are located. This is usually `%CommnonProgramFiles%\ArcGIS\Desktop<version>\Configuration\CATID`. Make sure there is a file with the name of your assembly and the extension `ecgf` (it may also have some GUID at the beginning, e.g. `{6d102248-13e2-40a0-8011-378543f63901}_MyAssembly.ecfg`). This is just some zip-archieve, you can also unzip it and find an xml-file containing the GUIDs of your commands and tools. If registering the assembly didn´t work with the step mentioned before, you can just delete that ecfg-file and re-build (!!) your assembly. Then verify the file was created in that folder.

If that still does not work, just delete your compiled assembly alltogether with an eventually existing ecfg-file and re-build again.

Comment: When I try to register the assembly using the command line I get the error `Could not load file or assembly "file: /// ... / Project1 / bin / Debug" or one of their dependencies. Access denied.`  But I am using the command line as "administrator". I tried to enter Windows using the `net user administrator / active: yes` command. Still denied access.

The location of "... ArcGIS \ Desktop10.5 \ bin \ Configuration \ CATID" no file with my build. There is only _esri.catid.ecfg_ .

Comment: I deleted the _esri.catid.ecfg_ file and the assembly file and rebuild the project again, then the error `Cannot register assembly" ... \ Project1 \ bin \ Debug \ Project1.dll "appears. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`

Comment: woe, that´s more descriptive than I ever got from the tool. Anyway the ecfg-files are not contained in ArcGIS´s program-folder, but in `%CommonProgramFiles%/ArcGIS`, which is `C:/Program Files (x86)/CommonFiles/ArcGIS` for me.

Comment: The _CATID_ folder is located only in the `C: \ Program Files (x86) \ ArcGIS \ Desktop10.5 \ bin \ Configuration` location. I don't have the location "C: / Program Files (x86) / CommonFiles \ ArcGIS \ Desktop 10.5 \ Configuration \ CATID". The folder `C: / Program Files (x86) / CommonFiles \ ArcGIS \ Desktop 10.5` contains the _bin_, _Help_, _Support_, _ThirdParty_ subfolders and that's it.